# Data being overwritten with simulated Hotel Wake-Up Call

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, signals

I posted this earlier on today but I realised I put up an old edition of my uncompiling code before, but this code compiles in gcc, I have to create a hotel wake-up call registry, which when a new alarm is generated it is printed out, placed correctly into the list (by order of the nearest alarm first) and then the time of the call occurs is printed out.

The problem is that when inserting nodes (insertNode()), the addedNode when added to the list overwrites the head, and writes into the next node, instead of just writing the alarmData into the head node.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define ETIMEDOUT 110

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

const int MAX_ROOM_NUMBER = 1000;
const int MAX_SECOND = 100;
static int NotCancelled = 0;
int REGISTER = 0;

typedef struct wakeUp
{

  int room; //Structure that has the room to awake
  time_t alarm;//and the time that the room wishes to wake
}wakeUp;

typedef struct node
{

  wakeUp awake; // Nodes used as a list to hold the of alarms ordered earliest node first
  struct node* nextNode;// it contains the struct WakeUp and a pointer to the next node
}node;

node * AlarmData;
pthread_t insert,wakeRoom;


static void *
printAlarmsData(node* first)
{
  if (first == NULL )
  {
    printf("This List Of Alarms is empty!\n");
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    node* p = first;
    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL )
    {
      printf("%d %s, \n", p->awake.room, ctime(&p->awake.alarm));
      count++;
      if (p->nextNode == NULL || count == 10)
      {
        return;
      }

    }
  }
}

static int
removeAlarm(wakeUp * first)
{ //When the alarm occurs remove the first Node

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); // Hold the lock

  time_t current_time;
  time(&current_time);

  if (current_time < first->alarm)
  {
    printf("Waiting...\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    AlarmData = AlarmData->nextNode;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return 1;
  }
}

int
length(node* first)
{ // Shows how many Alarms are left.
  node* p = first;
  int count = 0;

  while (p != NULL )
  {
    count++;
    p = p->nextNode;

  }
  return count;
}

// insert Node function

void
insertNode(node* addedNode)
{                 //this method here
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);           // head keeps getting overwritten instead
  node *head, *temp, *prev, *next;             // of writing data into AlarmData
  temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  head = AlarmData;
  temp = addedNode;
  temp->nextNode = NULL;
  if (!head)
  {
    printf("Head is null\n");
    head = temp;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Head is not null\n");
    prev = NULL;
    next = head;
    printf("Existing Data Showing Below\n");
    while (next && (next->awake.alarm) <= (addedNode->awake.alarm))
    {
      printf("----> %d %s\n", next->awake.room, ctime(&next->awake.alarm));
      prev = next;
      next = next->nextNode;
    }
    if (!next)
    {
      prev->nextNode = temp;
    }
    else
    {
      if (prev)
      {
        temp->nextNode = prev->nextNode;
        prev->nextNode = temp;
      }
      else
      {
        temp->nextNode = head;
        head = temp;
      }
    }

  }
  AlarmData = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  AlarmData = head;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

static void
cancelHandler(int signo)
{
  printf("\nAre you sure you want to exit this program Y/N:");
  char input;
  scanf("%c", &input);
  if (input == 'y')
  {
    NotCancelled = 1;
    wakeUp n = AlarmData->awake;
    while (AlarmData != NULL )
    {
      removeAlarm(&n);
    }

    pthread_cancel(insert);

    pthread_cancel(wakeRoom);

    pthread_join(insert, NULL );
    printf("Goodbye from insert thread");
    pthread_join(wakeRoom, NULL );
    printf("Goodbye from wakeUp thread");
    printf("Program Exited");
    return;
  }
}

static void *
insertHandler()
{
  printf("\nwent to insertHandler\n");
  while (NotCancelled == 0)
  {
    sleep(rand() % 2);
    int roomId = rand() % MAX_ROOM_NUMBER + 1;

    time_t timeToWake = time(NULL ) + (rand() % MAX_SECOND + 1);
    wakeUp wake;
    wake.room = roomId;
    wake.alarm = timeToWake;

    node newAlarm;
    newAlarm.awake = wake;
    REGISTER++;
    insertNode(&newAlarm);

    printf("After Registering:\t%d\t%s\n\n", roomId, ctime(&timeToWake));
  }
  return;
}
static void *
wakeRoomHandler()
{
  printf("\nwent to wakeRoomHandler\n");
  while (NotCancelled == 0)
  {
    sleep(rand() % 15);

    if (AlarmData != NULL )
    {
      wakeUp wake = AlarmData->awake;
      time_t timeToWake = AlarmData->awake.alarm;
      int roomId = AlarmData->awake.room;
      printf("Checking:\t%d\t%s\n\n", roomId, ctime(&timeToWake));
      int status = removeAlarm(&wake);
      if (status == 1)
      {
        printf("Wake Up:\t%d\t%s\n\n", roomId, ctime(&timeToWake));
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}

int
main(void)
{
  sigset_t set;
  sigemptyset(&set);
  sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
  sigset(SIGINT, cancelHandler);
  pthread_create(&insert, NULL, insertHandler, NULL );
  pthread_create(&wakeRoom, NULL, wakeRoomHandler, NULL );
  while (1)
  {
  }

  return (0);

}
```

Comment: BTW: The declaration `node * AlarmData;` being in global space normally gets initialized to 0.  Better to be explicit with `node * AlarmData = NULL;`

Comment: you have a memory leak, when temp = node you erase the pointer you created with malloc and save the pointer you passed as parameter. you need *temp = *node; to copy the data

Comment: After `AlarmData = head;`, the fields of `head` are not set.

Comment: `printAlarmsData()` misses arguments to `return`. Compile the code with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), then fix it until you get no more warnings, then compile it with symbole (`-g`) and debug it using gdb.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

```
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
head = AlarmData;                      
temp = addedNode;
```

In the above snippet you allocate memory for a new node and point `temp` at it. Two lines down you then point `temp` at `addedNode`. The memory you allocated in the first line is now lost, as you have overwritten your pointer to that memory. You probably intended to use `*temp = *addedNode` to copy the data in `addedNode` into `temp`.

You do not need to allocate a new node for `AlarmData` at the end of function. You simply need to update the AlarmData pointer to point to the new head (if head has indeed changed).

Answer (score 0):

You allocated a memory for temp but in the third line of function inserNode you assigned the address of addedNode into temp.

At the end of the function insertNode, you did the same thing with the global variable AlarmData where you allocated a memory for it but then assigned the address of head to AlarmData. In the end it is always the address of head that AlarmData ends up with, not a copy of head as you intended.

You should copy the contents of head to the allocated memory of AlarmData. Same with temp at the beginning of the code.

Note that pointers contain addresses, not values. Assigning a pointer address to another pointer is not the same as copying the values of the variables pointed by pointers.

Comment: I don't think he should be copying "the contents of head to the allocated memory of AlarmData". AlarmData is just a pointer to the head of the list. He should only have to make a copy of the `addedNode` parameter. The rest is maintaining the linked-list pointers, including the AlarmData pointer which is just a pointer to head.